# Whitelisting security settings with gmail SMTP for a forwarded email domain

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, spf, dkim

Having a little trouble with dkim, smtp and forwarded domains.

I basically want to use the gmail smtp servers from my google apps account to send mail from one of my domains, but I can't have that domain as either a domain alias or subdomain of google apps (for complicated reasons I won't go into...)

So. I've set up the SPF records for my original domain: domain1 
I've also set up SPF records on my new domain: domain2

However, I'm still getting the 'via domain1.com' on my emails.

I think the issue is that I have SPF but no DKIM, but I can't work out a way of getting a DKIM signature that I can pass without making the domain a domain alias which I really don't want to do. (It's not what it's for).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things - doublecheck that your domain2 SPF record designates your sending domain domain1.com as eligible to send email for domain2. So domain2 spf record should look something like this: `v=spf1 a:domain1.com ~all`.
The second thing is - yes, you need DKIM signature but actually it should work in both cases - one when you sign sending domain - here it is domain1.com or when otherwise you sign sender domain - and it is domain2 then.
So you can feel free to try continue with domain1.com and create DKIM for that both in DNS and in GoogleApps with help of GoogleApps control panel. It should work and be enough when you signing domain1.com with dkim as your sending domain.